# How do I Bind an Instance of a Model to a Parameter in a Controller Action

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to automatically bind an instance of a model to a parameter in a controller action? Is their any workaround for doing this if it does not already exist within Yii itself?
I know this is possible in Laravel and ASP.NET MVC. Here is what I want to achieve:

```
class PostController extends Controller {

    public function actionEdit(Post $post) {
        if($_POST['Post']){
            $post->attributes = $_POST['Post'];
            $post->save();
        }
        $this->render('edit', array('post'=>$post));
    }
}
```

Given a url like `localhost/?r=post/edit&post=1` 
[eg `Yii::app()->createUrl('post/edit',array('post'=>$mypost->id))`] the `id` 1 is converted to an instance of `CActiveRecord` 
 [i.e. `Post::model()->findByPk(1)` is called automatically]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your snippet it seems you are trying to pass both a $_POST and $_GET variable to your action.

Values in $_POST,$_GET are stored as associated arrays not objects themselves.
In Yii you can't do that directly load the model, however you can achieve your objective like this.

```
class PostController extends Controller {

    public function actionEdit($post) {
        $postModel = Post::model()->findByPk($post)
        $this->render('edit', array('post'=>$postModel));
    }
}
```

This is slightly longer but more useful if you want to bind additional conditions for example allow editing only is post is not deleted, or is active etc. You can use then `findByAttributes`, or `findAll` with additional conditions which may be implicit and not necessarily passed as parameter

Alternatively if you really required such a functionality you can write a component class with a custom action, where you can load a model as you wish

```
<?php
   class LoadModel extends CComponent {

    public function loadModel($type,$id){
        if(!in_array($type,$arrayofpossibleModels || !is_numeric($id)){ //Validation if $type is a model name is required.
            throw new CHttpException("400","Bad Request")
        }
        return $type::model()->findByPk($id);
    }

}
```